# Should I use cordova plugin for Ionic 4?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-audio-api

I would like to make an Ionic 4 app, which will use the users microphone.
I wanted to use the `Web Audio API` because I could do so much with it, like calculating Frequencies.

The app should run on both iOS and Android. 
When I run `ionic serve` or `ionic server --lab`, it is working. I can capture the user microphone and make media objects, but will it work on physical phones? (Yup. Didn't run it on any device yet).

I read, that for this feature I should use the `cordova-plugin-media-capture`. Do I really need it, or is it enough to use only the web audio api?

Comment: using a plugin can in most cases handle device-specific logics, like a request for permissions.

Answer (score 1):

if all the functionality you need you get from pure web API - you can avoid using additional plugins.

Use plugins when web API is restrictive or missing for what you are trying to achieve, or in the cases where web API is not standard and may work in chrome but not in Safari etc.